# Change JSON object structure and order in java

Tags: java, json

```
 //str is response from elastic.. 
JsonObject jsonObject = gson.fromJson(str, JsonObject.class);
"hits":{"total":{"value":0,"relation":"eq"},"max_score":null,"hits":[]}

       jsonObject
                .get("hits")
                .getAsJsonObject()
                .remove("total");

        jsonObject
                .get("hits")
                .getAsJsonObject().addProperty("total", "0");

"hits":{"hits":[],"total":"0"}

  need this format "hits":{"total": 0,"max_score":null,"hits":[]}
```

I am not getting the right order, How do I get total before hits? also it deleted maxscore

Comment: JSON isn't ordered

Comment: JSON elements aren't orderer, but maybe this link will solve your problem https://towardsdatascience.com/create-an-ordered-jsonobject-in-java-fb9629247d76

Comment: I'm pretty sure `getAsJsonObject()` returns a copy of the the input, so where are you assigning variables or printing your output?

Answer (score 1):

This explains how properties are ordered:
[https://javascript.info/object#ordered-like-an-object][1]

The problem here lies in the fact that non-integer properties are shown in creation order.
You added "total" last, so it shows up last.

While you can force the order of properties, it is not a good idea to rely on it. If the object is transformed by some function, all bets are off.

Usually the order of properties is not really relevant. If it is in your case, please provide some more context.

There usually is a better way of solving the problem than relying on the property order in an object.

if you want to sort the properties in your Json, then using a structure like:

```
{1:{key:"total", value:{"value":0,"relation":"eq"}},...}
```

would be much better. Not only are integer keys ordered ascending by default, you can force the order with sort functions in any language that this Json is used in. This is the only really reliable way I see here.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed by using the response and converting the json to pojo (via online converter (https://json2csharp.com/json-to-pojo)) Then ignored the total variable in the hits class. Then wrote it back out. use @JsonFilter("ignoreProperties") in the pojo class you want to ignore.

```
        FilterProvider filters = new 
       SimpleFilterProvider().addFilter("ignoreProperties",
       SimpleBeanPropertyFilter.serializeAllExcept("total"));
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        mapper.setFilterProvider(filters);
        EBean eBean = mapper.readValue(Result, EBean.class);
```